# Send file as attachment without using mutt and uuencode

Tags: shell-script, email

How can I send a file as an attachment via email in bash script, without using `mutt` and `uuencode`?

Comment: It's kind of weird to tag this [tag:mutt] when you specifically _don't_ want that....

Comment: sorry, newbie to this kind of forum.

Comment: On what operating system (if Linux, what distribution)? The available commands for sending mail differ quite a lot on different unix variants.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Message body" | mailx -s "Subject" -a "/path/to/attachment" somebody@example.com
```

or

```
cat "/path/to/messagebody.txt" | mailx -s "Subject" -a "/path/to/attachment" somebody@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I didnt get it work to send as attachment.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than 'it didn't work'?

Comment: mail: invalid option -- a
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]

Comment: I got this error.

Comment: Seems like the "mail" command doesnt support "-a" option.

Comment: Things that are not the same, partial list:  `mail`, `mailx`.

Comment: Same thing I get.
mailx: invalid option -- a Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ... [-- sendmail-options ...] mail [-iInNv] -f [name] mail [-iInNv] [-u user] –

Comment: It seems your system has `mailx` simply being a link to the `mail` tool.  Remedy this, and you're good to go.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - things that are not the same `mailx`.  There are several different versions of `mail`/`mailx`,  all with different options and capabilities.    On Debian, for example, there are (at least) `bsd-mailx`, `heirloom-mailx`, and `s-nail` packages which provide different versions of  `mail` and `mailx`.